# Conditional Formatting using e.Row.RowType for a Gridview in ASP.Net 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, gridview, datagridview

Afternoon All,

I have been searching the net for some help in reference to applying some conditional formatting based on a value in my grid view.  I am using Studio 2010 in the form of VB.

I essentially have a gridview and want to highlight a row of data green when the 'Status' for items in my gridview are'On-Line'.

I have been been reviewing a solution [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1807228.aspx/1).

I believe this solution may work but i still get an error (Blue line) under the e.Row when i apply this to my code.  This simply states that 'Row' is not a member of System.EventArgs.

I have already added `Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow` to the top of my web page and i still have no joy.

Please find below my code.  If someone could review this and let me know what the issue is i would be most greatful.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub


Protected Sub grdCriticalSystems_DataBound(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles grdCriticalSystems.DataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        If DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status").ToString() = "On-Line" Then
            e.Row.BackColour = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        End If
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Many thanks is advance for any help.

Regards
Betty

Answer (score 1):

Afternoon All,

I have managed to complete the above by amndeding the code to the following...

```
Protected Sub grdCriticalSystems_DataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdCriticalSystems.DataBound
```

I needed to replace system.EventArgs with GridViewRowEventArgs.  this has now worked a treat.

Betty